# Max sum by going from left to right in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

Program specs:

- In a matrix you start from a point in the left-most column and from there you may go in three directions: **right**, **up-right diagonal**, **down-right diagonal** (i.e from point **(i,j)** you can go to: **(i,j+1)** , **(i-1,j+1)** or **(i+1,j+1)**.
- Stop at the end of the matrix (right-most side).
- Determine the best path so that the sum of the values you pass through is highest, and print the highest sum.

**My problem is**: I wrote a method for this program, however it doesn't return the right value in all cases. I need **help in modifying my method** so it works for all cases.

This is my code:

```
//Matrix size boundaries
int x,y;

//read x and y...

//Matrix M
int[][] M=new int[x][y];

//read M...

//Goes through left-most column and prints highest sum of all sums returned
public void GoThroughLeftColumn()
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        {
            sum=Math.max(sum, GoThroughMatrix(i,0));
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

//Returns the highest sum for point (i,j)
public int GoThroughMatrix(int i, int j)
    {
        int sum;
        //if out of matrix-->return 0
        if(i>=x||j>=y||i<0||j<0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sum=0;
            for(int line=-1;line<2;line++)
            {
                sum=Math.max(M[i][j]+GoThroughMatrix(i+line,j+1), sum);
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }
```

For Matrix:

```
1 3 4
7 2 1
4 1 8
```

The output is 17. This is correct.
7,2,8 is the path with the highest yield

For Matrix:

```
7 1 8
7 6 7
7 1 3
5 5 4
```

The output is 29. The correct output is 21 for path 7,6,8.

Comment: This is a classical graph-theory problem :) You need the 'most expensive path' from left to right. See for inspiration: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Dijkstra.html

Comment: Seems to me more like a Maximum Flow instead of Single Source "Largest" Distance

Comment: I am looking for a recursive method to go through the matrix in the specified way and determine highest sum. Dijkstra is rather complicated. I have to modify my method somehow.

Comment: It looks like you implemented a greedy algorithm, which won't necessarily produce the optimal output.  Think about the two number sequences 7 -> 7 -> 1, versus 7 -> 6 -> 7.

Comment: I don't think this is greedy, it doesn't just check the next maximum value, it checks the next maximum sum of values for the remaining path. At least, that's what it should do. That's why I call it recursively, it examines each path from the point (i,j).

Comment: @dannychris37 There's no recursion in your posted code.  Also, this problem probably shouldn't be solved recursively.  I don't know if it's small enough that it can be though.

Comment: Sorry, I replaced travel1 with GoThroughMatrix. I forgot to do that innitialy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a graph-theory problem (though there are also probably dynamic programming solutions as well). Here's how to go about thinking about a graph theory problem:

1. How can you transform your input into a graph (Nodes + Edges)? In this case, the nodes are fairly simple - each entry in the matrix is a node. For the edges, consider the rules of your game - you're only allowed to move right, upright, or downright. Thus, when constructing the graph, add edges from each node to the three nodes located right, upright, and downright from it.
2. What is the optimal criteria? For a given path, what determines whether that path is ideal or not? In this case, we are looking for largest summed value.
3. Is there any worry about infinite looping? In this case no, because all edges must move to the right (preventing cycles). This plus the fact that the graph is finite means all of the paths will be finite as well.

To summarize, you should create a graph that stores the matrix and internalizes the rules of the game (in terms of right/upright/downright movement), then write a path finding algorithm that will return the greatest value path on the graph.

Dijkstra's is the general solution that is certainly applicable for your problem, but you can probably cut some corners because you know that each node's index in any path is equal to its column number. Therefore you can just go down each column finding the optimal path that passes through that node by taking the maximum of its three possible predecessors (left, upleft, downleft), then taking the maximum value of these values in the final column. This ends up more dynamic programming, just on a graph.